# JQuery: How to retain active tab after regenerating tabs dynamically on database changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have 1 static tab which is my default tab and 2 dynamic tabs that are dynamically generating on the basis of database records.

On database changes I use the `$('.dynamic').remove();` JQuery remove method to remove the elements and regenerating the elements dynamically.

**Dynamic tabs and content are generated on the basis of database records**

On first page load, 1 static and 2 dynamic tabs are loaded...

[image: Dynamically Created Tabs]

Whenever a change is made in the database either a record is deleted or modified,
I have to regenerate the tabs dynamically and show the contents in it.

[image: Dynamically Created Tabs after callbacks]

The problem is, when user is on dynamic tabs and change is made in the database,
all the dynamic content first removed and then added again into the page. Due to this reason the content was removed of that tab and it displays nothing until user toggle or click on the tab again.

**The problem which I figured out is, I have lost the active tab and content. That's why whenever a change is made in the database, it first remove all the dynamic tab and its content and then add again dynamically.**

If I use `$('.dynamic').show()` it will all the content of tabs as stacked on each other.

Is there any way to maintain the tab and its content active on database changes.

OR

By using `$('.dynamic').show()` and maintain the tabs and its content.

### Code:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
$('.dynamic').remove();

$.each(data, function (arrayId, item) {

     $('.nav-tabs').append('<li class="dynamic" > <a href="#tab' + (arrayId + 2) + '" role="tab"  data-toggle="tab">' + (item.Name) + '</a></li>');


     $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane dynamic" id="tab' + (arrayId + 2) + '">' +

             // Content Here

     '</div>');
});
```

**What I want to do is to retain the tab active that was displayed to the user before removing dynamically.
In case if the tab data is deleted from the database, first tab should be selected.**

No `postback` Or `callback` in this problem.
The server pushing the content to all the clients when a change is made in the database.

Comment: It would be useful if you could share a bit more code. But the theory goes like this: before you reload the dynamic tabs from DB you should "remember" (e.g. store in a variable) the currently active tab. And once you've reloaded the dynamic tabs, you can either reactivate the last active tab, or activate the default tab if the previously active tab has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I have made for this particular problem, When server pushing data to all the connected clients and No `PostBack` Or `CallBack` is actually happened;

What I need to do is to keep the active tab reference and remove all dynamic content and make the tab active that was previously active.

To keep the reference of the active tab,

```
var activeTab = $("li.active a").attr("href");
```

It will return me the `href` value of the active tab in a variable `activeTab`.

Then I remove all the dynamic content by class name `dynamic`

```
$('.dynamic').remove();
```

Then I generates the dynamic tabs and content again (Whenever a change is made in the database, dynamic tabs are removed and regenerates again with updated content)

Below is the code to generate tabs and its content dynamically

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);

$.each(data, function (arrayId, item) {

    $('.nav-tabs').append('<li class="dynamic" > <a href="#tab' + (arrayId + 2) + '" role="tab"  data-toggle="tab">' + (item.Name) + '</a></li>');


    $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane dynamic" id="tab' + (arrayId + 2) + '">' +

        // Content Here

    '</div>');
});
```

After regeneration, First I remove the class 'active' from everywhere

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
```

Then get the length of the `activeTab` variable, *(if a tab reference exist, it will return **1** otherwise it will return **0**)*

```
var ifExist = $(activeTab).length;
```

Then a simple if-else solve the problem for me,

**If tab reference exist, the if block executes and make the tab and its content active**

**Else it will simple active the first default hard coded tab and its content**

```
if (ifExist > 0) {

    $('a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

    $(activeTab).addClass('active');

} else {

    $('a[href="#tab1"]').parent().addClass('active');

    $('#tab1').addClass('active');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, a simple solution would be to store the active tab before regenerating the tabs using sessionStorage or localStorage (refer [storage guide @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)).

for example, you'll save a specific attribute that uniquely identifies the active tab such as `id`, `title` etc in localStorage upon selecting the tab, like

```
sessionStorage.setItem('selected', attributeValue);
```

Once the tabs are regenerated, you can retrieve the value from sessionStorage like

```
sessionStorage.getItem('selected');
```

and use it to `show()` the particular tab.

(*Can't be more specific with the info provided*)